# Why isn't character formatting in Word showing up in XML?

Tags: c#, xml, ms-word, openxml-sdk

I work with Microsoft Word files at the moment in the .docx format (FYI: I converted the format from .doc to .docx). All I need to do is to read the file to get some information out of it. I use OpenXml and it worked perfect so far.

But a few files have text which is bold in the Word document but when I look at the Inner XML I can't find the tag  and there is also no bold property for the text or single elements if I run through it. And therefore again I can't match the pattern for the information I need to get.

Are there any other tags or anything else that could cause that problem? I also thought the problem could be the text indent. But I've changed that and still no result.

Here is the XML without any changes. The text is "Artikel anzeigen (og)":

```
<w:pPr xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
  <w:pStyle w:val="PosText" />
  <w:ind w:left="-6" />
  <w:rPr>
    <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
    <w:sz w:val="20" />
  </w:rPr>
</w:pPr>
<w:r xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
  <w:rPr>
    <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
    <w:sz w:val="20" />
  </w:rPr>
  <w:t xml:space="preserve">Artikel anzeigen </w:t>
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidRPr="00185315" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
  <w:rPr>
    <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
    <w:sz w:val="20" />
  </w:rPr>
<w:t>(</w:t></w:r>
<w:r xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
  <w:rPr>
    <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
    <w:sz w:val="20" />
  </w:rPr>
  <w:t>og</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidRPr="00185315" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
  <w:rPr>
    <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
    <w:sz w:val="20" />
  </w:rPr>
  <w:t>)</w:t>
</w:r>
```

I don't know how else to test for the bold property. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

Character formatting can be defined at many levels in OOXML.

In your case it's not defined directly but likely is a part of the `PosText` style which is referenced,

```
<w:pStyle w:val="PosText" />
```

but not defined in the XML excerpt you've provided.

---

**Update**: The workaround you mention in your [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33695946/290085) can be understood as follows:  The *Format übertragen* command is [*Format Painter*](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Copy-formatting-using-the-Format-Painter-b9fe82ea-c0a0-41de-837b-d2f15dd41ea9) in English.  Applying "Format Painter" transfers the formatting styles directly to the paragraph or run of text, saving you from having to chase down the reference indirectly via a named style.

**Update 2**: After indenting your XML, it appears that `PosText` may not be in scope, but the principle remains: Another style for a (not shown) containing `w:p` of the `w:r` could have a similar style influencing the formatting of the text in question.

Comment: Thanks for the information! I found a workaround for it but if it happens again I have a look into that :)

Comment: Answer updated to explain why your workaround works.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it is a little bit funny to post an anwer to my own question shortly after I've opened it but I've found a workaround for my problem. So here was my solution in case someone has the same problem:

In Word, I marked the text with the correct format and and clicked onto the button "Transfer format" (It's "Format übertragen" in my german version - I'm not sure what the correct translation is here) and then I marked the incorrect text and as soon as you let go of the mouse it changes the format to the correct one (if you have marked the right one).

I really have no idea why this needs to be done but now it is marked as bold in the XML.

Comment: "Format übertragen" is "Format Painter" in English.   See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33695583/290085) for an explanation of why this helps you.